# Django - How to access files from view with two forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a view with two forms:

```
def CreateNewUserView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserCreationForm(request.POST, prefix='user_form')
        user_profile_form = UserProfileCreationForm(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='user_profile_form')
        if user_form.is_valid():
            new_user = user_form.save()

            if user_profile_form.is_valid():            
                profile_picture = request.FILES['profile_picture']

                new_user_profile = UserProfile(user=new_user, profile_picture=profile_picture,
                )
                new_user_profile.save()

                username = user_form.cleaned_data['username']
                password = user_form.cleaned_data['password1']
                user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
                login(request, user)

                return HttpResponseRedirect('/dashboard/')
    else:
        # Allow user to select a role
        user_form = UserCreationForm(prefix='user_form')
        user_profile_form = UserProfileCreationForm(prefix='user_profile_form')
        return render(request, 'dashboard/create_user.html', {
            'user_form':user_form,
            'user_profile_form':user_profile_form,
        })
```

Right now, `user_profile_form` doesn't validate when I access `profile_picture` through the `request.FILES` array. How would I correctly access the file?

Thanks!

Comment: be sure to add 'enctype="multipart/form-data">' to form in template file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
profile_picture = user_profile_form.cleaned_data['profile_picture']
if profile_picture:
     new_user_profile = UserProfile()
     new_user_profile.user=new_user
     new_user_profile.profile_picture=profile_picture
     new_user_profile.save()
```

Your are validating your form and you are not taking cleaned_date

I hope that helps..

Comment: Thanks a lot! Tried it before but I guess another problem stopped this from working.